# Deleting a document from Firestore via Auto-generated document ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a Property Rental application on Android using Firebase Firestore. Right now, I'm trying to implement a method to delete a specific document (property) within my collection inside Firestore. I figure it is by referencing the auto-generated ID for that particular document, but I simply couldn't get around it.

This is how the delete feature should work:

1. User clicks on a property item from the [`RecyclerView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55hav.jpg)
2. It displays a full profile of that [property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUAIR.jpg)
3. User clicks the delete button from the top right corner and deletes the property from the [Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mo95.jpg)

Here is my code where I'm stucked at:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        // The delete button
        case R.id.action_delete_btn:
            // Do this when user clicks on delete button
            Toast.makeText(PropertyProfile.this, "You tried to delete this property", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            deleteItem(item.getOrder());
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

// Here's my problem
private void deleteItem(int index) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts")
        .document("[DOCUMENT ID RIGHT HERE!]")
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(PropertyProfile.this, "You successfully deleted this property", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In order to use the document id that you are looking for, first you need to store it in a variable. When you are adding a document to the database and you are using a call to `document()` method without passing an argument, a unique id is generated. To get that id, you should use the following code:

```
String documentId = postsRef.document().getId();
postsRef.document(documentId).set(yourModelObject);
```

In which `postsRef` is the `CollectionReference` object of your `Posts` collection and `yourModelObject` is the object of your `Post` class. I also recommend you store that id, as a property of your Post document.

Once you have this id, you can use in your refence like this:

```
firebaseFirestore
    .collection("Posts")
    .document(documentId)
    .delete().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```