# Unable to update firestore document

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In this app, I try to update the payment status after placing an order, but the problem happens when the app tries to access the path of the document, it's not seeing the document and therefore it's creating a new one

firstly this **placeOrderDetails** and it's called each time the user tries to make the order.

```
 override suspend fun placeOrderDetails(
        orderID: String,
        cartItemModelList: ArrayList<CartItemModel>,
        address: String,
        fullName: String,
        pinCode: String,
        paymentMethod: String
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.emit(Resource.Loading())


        cartItemModelList.forEach {
            if (it.type == CartItemModel.CART_ITEM) {

                val orderDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()

                orderDetails["ORDER ID"] = orderID
                orderDetails["PRODUCT ID"] = it.productId.toString()
                orderDetails["PRODUCT IMAGE"] = it.productImage.toString()
                orderDetails["PRODUCT NAME"] = it.productName.toString()
                orderDetails["USER ID"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!
                orderDetails["PRODUCT QUANTITY"] = it.productQuantity!!
                if (!it.cuttedPrice.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["CUTTED PRICE"] = it.cuttedPrice!!
                }

                orderDetails["PRODUCT PRICE"] = it.productPrice!!

                if (!it.selectedCouponId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["COUPON ID"] = it.selectedCouponId!!
                }

                if (!it.discountedPrice.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = it.discountedPrice!!
                } else {
                    orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = ""
                }
                orderDetails["ORDER DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["PACKED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["SHIPPED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["DELIVERED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["CANCELLED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "ORDERED"
                orderDetails["PAYMENT METHOD"] = paymentMethod
                orderDetails["ADDRESS"] = address
                orderDetails["FULL NAME"] = fullName
                orderDetails["PIN CODE"] = pinCode
                orderDetails["FREE COUPONS"] = it.freeCoupons!!
                if (it.deliveryPrice != null) {
                    orderDetails["DELIVERY PRICE"] = it.deliveryPrice!!

                    Log.d(TAG, "placeOrderDetails: DELIVERY PRICE ${it.deliveryPrice}")
                }else {
                    orderDetails["DELIVERY PRICE"] = "Free"
                }

                firestore.collection("ORDERS")
                    .document(orderID)
                    .set(orderDetails)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Success(true)
                    }.addOnFailureListener { ex ->
                        result.value = Resource.Error(ex.message.toString())

                    }

            } else {
                val orderDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()

                orderDetails["Total Items"] = it.totalItems!!
                orderDetails["Total Items price"] = it.totalItemsPrice!!
                orderDetails["Delivery Price"] = it.deliveryPrice!!
                orderDetails["Total Amount"] = it.totalAmount!!
                orderDetails["Saved Amount"] = it.savedAmount!!
                orderDetails["PAYMENT STATUS"] = "not paid"
                orderDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "Cancelled"

                firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
                    .collection("OtherDetails")
                    .document().set(orderDetails)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

                    }
            }
        }
        return result

    }
```

and this **updateOrderStatus** and it called after I get the order response `onPaymentSuccess` or `onPaymentError`

```
override suspend fun updateOrderStatus(
        orderID: String,
        paymentStatus: String,
        orderStatus: String
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.value = Resource.Loading()

        val updateStatusHashMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()

        updateStatusHashMap["PAYMENT STATUS"] = paymentStatus
        updateStatusHashMap["ORDER STATUS"] = orderStatus


        val test = firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
            .collection("OtherDetails")
            .document()


        test.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.exists()) {

                test.update(updateStatusHashMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {

                        val userOrder = hashMapOf<String, Any>()

                        userOrder["Order_ID"] = orderID

                        firestore.collection("USERS").document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                            .collection("USER_ORDERS").document(orderID)
                            .set(userOrder)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                            }.addOnFailureListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                            }

                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                    }
            }else {
               test.set(updateStatusHashMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
//                result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                        val userOrder = hashMapOf<String, Any>()

                        userOrder["Order_ID"] = orderID

                        firestore.collection("USERS").document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                            .collection("USER_ORDERS").document(orderID)
                            .set(userOrder)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                            }.addOnFailureListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                            }

                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                    }
            }
        }
        return result

    }
```

the following the two methods' response and it's called after I place the order

```
 override fun onPaymentSuccess(razorpayPaymentId: String?, p1: PaymentData?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPaymentSuccess: ${p1?.orderId}")

        mainActivityViewModel.updatePaymentState(true)

        p1?.orderId?.let { mainActivityViewModel.getOrderId(orderId = it) }

        if (p1 != null) {
            mainActivityViewModel.updateOrderStatus(p1.orderId,"Paid", orderStatus = "ORDERED")
        }

    }

    override fun onPaymentError(errorCode: Int, p1: String?, p2: PaymentData?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPaymentError: $p1")
        mainActivityViewModel.updatePaymentState(false)

        p2?.orderId?.let { mainActivityViewModel.getOrderId(it) }

        when (errorCode) {
            Checkout.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                mainActivityViewModel.updateOrderStatus(p2?.orderId!!,"not paid","NETWORK_ERROR")
            }
            Checkout.INVALID_OPTIONS -> {
                mainActivityViewModel.updateOrderStatus(p2?.orderId!!,"not paid","INVALID_OPTIONS")

            }
            Checkout.PAYMENT_CANCELED -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPaymentError: error ${p2.toString()}", )

                mainActivityViewModel.updateOrderStatus(p2?.orderId!!,"not paid","CANCELED")

            }
            Checkout.TLS_ERROR->{

                mainActivityViewModel.updateOrderStatus(p2?.orderId!!,"not paid","TLS_ERROR")

            }
        }

    }
```

the problem happens in in this particular line and it should be like the following, Because of this error I separated the process into two part, firstly check If the document exist or not, and if exist it should update

```
firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
            .collection("OtherDetails")
            .document()
            .update(updateStatusHashMap)
```

And in the end, I got this result inside `OtherDetails` Collection, It's created two documents instead of just updating the current one with two fields `ORDER STATUS` and `PAYMENT STATUS`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that behavior because you're calling the [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) function without passing the ID of the document as an argument. This function:

> Returns a DocumentReference pointing to a new document with an **auto-generated ID** within this collection.

So instead of updating an existing document:

```
firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
        .collection("OtherDetails")
        .document()
//               
        .update(updateStatusHashMap)
```

You're trying to update a brand-new one, which obviously doesn't exist, hence the behavior. To solve this, you have to pass to the [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) function the exact ID of the document you want to be updated.

```
firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
        .collection("OtherDetails")
        .document("ID-OF-THE-DOCUMENT")
//                       
        .update(updateStatusHashMap)
```

Comment: but the id of the document is randomly set when placing the order and therefore I'll not be able to know the exact id

Comment: Yes, that's correct, is generated when you're placing an order, but you can know the ID. So please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361039/deleting-a-document-from-firestore-via-auto-generated-document-id) out. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I tried [this](https://imgur.com/DDQu07z) unfortunately didn't work

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You should pass to the `document()` function as an argument the **exact** ID of the document in the database. Give it a try and tell me if it works.